Are LTE-M or NB IoT Sim modules (eg from simcom) carriers restricted?
I am currently planning to build a board which will have to use LTE-M or NB-IoT technology due to their low consumption and because I do not need large data bandwidth. The targeted region is Africa.
I decided to check on some GSM modules from SIMCom and Quectel.  I later filtered my choice to SIM7500 and SIM7000. I then saw in their product details (as shown below) some stated carriers and am confused if that means the module would only work with those carriers' SIMs only.
Do you have a better suggestion regarding what will work as per the region of usage?

